# How do I set the scale for the Hero Image in a winRT Hub Application

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am building a windows store application in vs2013 preview with the Hub App Template. I am working on the hero image section.

My development box has a 30" monitor and a resolution of 2560x1600. I am attempting to get my hero image which I have scaled versions of 80,100,140,and 180 to load correctly. Everything works fine until I go to local machine and then it shows a clipped version of the 100% scale image. It should be scaling to the 180%. It is also clipping the area of the hub section to only show about 40% of the width the hero image should be.

Is there anyway to change how the scaling works so that it is pulling the correct 180% scale? I assume it thinks I am on a TV set and not a monitor because the Device section for 23" and 27" show only a scale of 100% and they are close to the results I am seeing in my local machine build.

Editing to provide more information.

```
    <HubSection Width="1024">
        <HubSection.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/CavePainting.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </HubSection.Background>
    </HubSection>
```

Images are titled:

```
CavePainting.scale-80.png
CavePainting.scale-100.png
CavePainting.scale-140.png
CavePainting.scale-180.png
```

The images scale properly as long as I am in simulator mode, but once I go into Local Machine they do not, they scale back to 100% and there is a lot of clipping. It seems as long as the device size is at 10.6", via simulator the resolution scales properly. On my development box. Which lets me target tablets without any issues but I also want to target desktops with this application and the scaling is killing my layout.

Comment: We'll need to know a bit more, such as if you've done the scaling correctly (by either using the folders or adding file extensions). One thing to try is enabling "Ease of Access", which will generally upscale the images so you can test to make sure they're being pulled at all. Also, are you using (or is the template using) a `Viewbox`? If so, that may be having an effect on the scaling.

Comment: Edited the post to include more information.

Comment: Ah, I think the issue may be using `Stretch="UniformToFill"` Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch.aspx). It also may be due to just setting the Width/Height, but not the DecodeWidth/DecodeHeight. Look [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/forums/windows-8-development/resizing-an-image-without-losing-any-quality-in-windows-store-app) for more information on that.